# Training data in a training set

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

Am, trying to train a model in my training set using **scikit-learn**,  but getting this error:

```
 ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[90.  4.].
 Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

### step 1: split x and y into training and testing set

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.4, random_state = 4)
```

## checking the shape of the new splited x value(training and testing)

```
X_train = X_train.shape
X_test = X_test.shape
print(X_train)
print(X_test)
```

## checking the shape of the new splited y value(training and testing)

```
y_train = y_train.shape
y_test = y_test.shape
print(y_train)
print(y_test)
```

### step 2: Training our model on the training set(using logistics regression)

```
logR = LogisticRegression()
logR = logR.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

### Running this code I got the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are replacing data points by their shapes:

```
X_train = X_train.shape
X_test = X_test.shape
y_train = y_train.shape
y_test = y_test.shape
```

Remove these lines and re-run.

Answer (score 0):

> You did great work but one wrong thing you did  :You replace train and test data by their shape which is 1D that's why you face this error

```
 #replace these line

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.4, random_state = 4)

print( X_train.shape)
print( X_test.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(y_test.shape)

logR = LogisticRegression()
logR = logR.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Now it work fine
```